# What does the red dot means in Review tasks?

Tags: support

From time to time I see a red dot on some review tasks. At this very same moment, I see a red dot on **Low Quality Posts**

[image]

However the Low Quality Posts queue is empty. And before this, it had posts to review and still the red dot was visible, so it seems the queue doesn't affect this.

Anyways, what does this red dot means?

Comment: it's good taste to explain the down votes so we can all learn from our mistakes

Comment: Just a theory. The downvote is by the person who coded the red dot. (Yes, it's a joke. No, I don't intend to offend the devs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue. The fact that the red dot appears means that there are actually *still* pending reviews to be completed. However, for some reasons, *you can't get those review items*.

Based on the report on Meta SE: [Please don't show the red dot indicator for review items I can't do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310798),

> As a result, there are various circumstances where the review indicator gives false information:
>
> - There are items in a queue which the user does not have the reputation to review. (I only know of this happening in the suggested edits queue, where tag wiki edits land in the same queue as post edits.) This once caused me some consternation.
> - There is a single pending suggested edit, which is currently being reviewed by someone else and has been "checked out" to that reviewer.
> - **The reviewer has already voted on a post in the queue (e.g. flagging a current Low Quality post as NAA or VLQ externally, or externally voting to close or reopen a post currently in one of those queues)**
> - **The reviewer has skipped reviews**
> - The user has had a review ban
> - The user has reviewed all items in a queue, but they have not left it yet
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine for this particular case)</sup>

Comment: OK, so it's a bug, +1 for that (although I have to say it's known TO YOU, not me, otherwise I wouldn't ask). Now, what would be the difference between the red dot and the grey dot? They both mean *there are still pending reviews to be completed*, so what does the red dot means exactly? I find quite disturbing that an UX board has such kind of mysterious behaviors

Comment: @Devin The red dot means "in danger" while the grey dot simply means "available". However, the threshold for the red dot depends on per site's hourly samples of pending tasks as per [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226)

Comment: thank you. Completely unexpected UX